Doubts about Eventloop and Global Execution Context
In vanilla JS can eventloop take a function from the callback queue and push it onto the callstack even before the JS engine completes executing Global Execution Context.

The event loop does not do anything while JS code is executing. It only gets to do something when code has run to completion and the call stack is empty.

The "event loop" is not ECMAScript ("vanilla") terminology. The specification does however define some rules that a host should follow when dealing with jobs. One of those rules is that the engine does not initiate any queued jobs while JavaScript code is still executing. A job only gets its turn when code has run to completion and the call stack is empty.
See the ECMAScript spec on Jobs and Job Queues:

Execution of a Job can be initiated only when there is no running execution context and the execution context stack is empty.

And also Jobs and Host Operations to Enqueue Jobs:

Their implementations must conform to the following requirements:

At some future point in time, when there is no running context in the agent for which the job is scheduled and that agent's execution context stack is empty, the implementation must:

Perform any host-defined preparation steps.
Invoke the Job Abstract Closure.
Perform any host-defined cleanup steps, after which the execution context stack must be empty.


Only one Job may be actively undergoing evaluation at any point in time in an agent.

Once evaluation of a Job starts, it must run to completion before evaluation of any other Job starts in an agent.




This answer applies to JavaScript execution in browsers
No, in JavaScript (specifically in the browser), the event loop cannot take a function from the callback queue and push it onto the call stack before the JavaScript engine completes executing the Global Execution Context.
JavaScript Execution in the Browser

Call Stack: A stack with all function calls. The function at the top is executed.
Execution Context: When the JavaScript engine receives a JavaScript file, it creates a global execution context (GEC). When a function is called, it creates a function execution context (FEC). When the context is created, it does three things:

Variable Environment: stores and hoists variables and function declarations
Lecical Environment: creates a scope chain so that variables and function declarations are available only within their scope
this: creates the "this" keyword that refers to the execution context, and is different for GEC and FEC.

Note: In the ECMAScript specification the this value is a binding associated with the execution context, but it does not refer to the execution context itself (thanks to @trinkot for the hint).




Task Queue: A queue of functions waiting to be executed after asynchronous operations complete.

Macrotasks: setTimeout, setInterval and other events
Microtasks: Promise callbacks (.then(), .catch(), .finally()), MutationObserver callbacks


Event Loop: A loop that continuously checks the Call Stack and the Task Queues. It pushes tasks from the queues to the Call Stack when the Call Stack is empty.

Event Loop - Execution Order in the Browser

Synchronous Code: The JavaScript engine starts by executing synchronous code in the global execution context (GEC).
Asynchronous Code (Macrotask): The event loop picks the next macrotask from the macrotask queue and executes it.
Asynchronous Code (Microtasks): All microtasks are executed after each macrotask. If executing a microtask enqueues more microtasks, they are added to the microtask queue and will be executed in the same iteration.
Render Updates (browser only): The browser may perform UI updates on the mainthread
repeat: The event loop moves back to step 2 to process the next macrotask.

Further reading

WHATWG specification: event loop
MDN Guide: Microtask guide
Stackoverflow: Difference between microtask and macrotask within an event loop context


The WHATWG specification is the "HTML Standard" which concerns Web implementations. This is not generally applicable to any JavaScript implementation. Your answer also seems to mix in some NodeJs specific information, which is another category of implementation,...

""this" keyword that refers to the execution context,": that is not the standard meaning of "execution context". See ECMAScript specification for the meaning of that concept.

I will update my answer corresponding and try to find resources to it. Thanks for the hint. I posted the answer with the knowledge I got.
